# Creating a object for instances in a json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, class, python-3.8

So I have a JSON file

```
{
  "Vehicles": [
    {
      "Name": "Car",
      "ID": 1
    },
    {
      "Name": "Plane",
      "ID": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

and I created the class in python

```
class vehicleclass: 
    def __init__(self, vname, vid):
        self.name = vname
        self.id = vid
```

what I would like to do is create an instance of the object vehicles for each vehicle in the JSON, I am reading from the file as shown here

```
with open('vehicle.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
```

I then run this piece of code

```
for each in data['Vehicles']:
```

how do I create an instance of vehicleclass using each 'name' iteration in the JSON file

note I realize I can get the value for each 'name' by calling `each['Name']` in the for loop

Comment: It's not very clear what you need help with. Do you know how to create an instance of your class outside of the JSON related stuff? What do you intend to do with the instances, after you create them (an obvious choice would be to put them into a new list). I'd imagine that `instance = vehicleclass(each['Name'], each['ID'])` would be a good start.

Comment: ah, my bad new to this and programming so trying to be as clear as possible, 

so I'm not sure how to explain this but the idea is that each iteration in the JSON becomes its own copy of vehicleclass

What I mean of that is that as there are 2 vehicles in the JSON file it will create the vehicleclass for Car and Plane

so that Car would be a new object with name Car and id 1
and that plane would be an object as well with Plane and 2, if that makes sense

eventually, I will turn this concept into creating a text-based game that allows you to make your own monster list, etc via JSON

Comment: i do know that say running ship = vehicleclass("ship" , "3")
would create the object ship as an instance of vehicleclass, just not sure how I can take all my data from the JSON and do this

Comment: `v = vehicleclass(each['Name'], each['ID'])` <-- It's not clear what you are asking beyond that. Maybe you could show what you want after the loop?

Comment: This is sort of the answer im looking for but I'm wondering if there's a way to use a variable name that will change as it loops through the for loop instead of using a static variable v? @MarkMeyer

Comment: @MarkMeyer so the loop itself will create x amount of variables for each loop of the for loop
instead of me saying `v = vehicleclass(each['Name'], each['ID'])` it would create multiple of these for me if that makes sense, I'm not sure how to explain

Comment: @Vishal-Singh's answer below is the way to go, then each vehicle can be found like `vehicle_instances[0]`, `vehicle_instances[1]` etc. It's unlikely that  creating a bunch of individual variables it the right choice.

Comment: ah thank you @MarkMeyer yes I realize that lots of variables could be confusing wasn't sure how else to do it, but this will work if I got how it runs correctly

Comment: Trying to get results that are like `Car = vehicleclass("Car", 1)` and `Plane = vehicleclass("Plane", 2)` would be a bad idea. Variable names are not data, they're for the programmer to use while *writing* the code. If you can't know in advance what names are in the JSON file, you can't write code using the variables you'd define. Using a data structure instead (such as a list or a dict) is a much better idea.

Comment: @Blckknght thank you I get that now, my brain just couldn't think of any other way to do this, but the way mentioned below works perfectly for what Im looking for and this explanation really helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I understand I think this should achieve it.

```
with open("vehicle.json") as json_file:  # opens your vehicles.json file

    # this will load your file object into json module giving you a dictionary if its a valid json
    data = json.load(json_file)

    # this list comprehension uses data dictionary to generate your vehicleclass instances
    vehicle_instances = [
        vehicleclass(vehicle["Name"], vehicle["ID"]) for vehicle in data["Vehicles"]
    ]
```

Comment: Hey this looks good can I just check I'm understanding this correctly?
so this opens the file and creates a list called vehicle_instances, and in that list is 2 instances of the object vehicleclass where the data is coming from the vehicles in the json file?

Comment: @HarrisonO'Donnell indeed that is correct. I've added comments.